# Is it possible to detect Android application uninstall?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

How to start an Activity ,Service or broadcast receiver before an application uninstalled by the user who has earlier installed the app on his/her device?

If possible please help me? and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can't detect for your app whether it has installed or uninstalled but for other apps you can get this detail using this `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
<receiver android:name=".UninstallApkReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Please see the dolphin browser functionality they can do this thing

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but is it legal for the Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

YES using Accessibility Service you can detect Uninstall event and then read rhe screen to find app name.
Voodo app uses this concept.

Comment: I just tested this an confirmed it works in Android 7.1.1. You can try out the app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voodoo.android

Comment: Hi, Dhruv. Happy Diwali!! If you are aware of the Quora app, when I delete the app, it shows my account has been deactivated. Any idea how to do it?