# How to inform server about app uninstalled from device?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to send server request in forming about my app uninstallation. Overall motive behind this is that I have to inform server about my app uninstallation.How do I acheive this scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect Android application uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141707/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-application-uninstall)

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an unique ID to every device (on which your app is installed). Once a day you just "ping" the device with the ID. If it response, it is still installed. If not, the app is uninstalled. It's quite difficult, cuz you have to handle things like airplane mode, or no internet connection at all.

Comment: what about if user population is 1 million ...in that case how we can manage.

Comment: Interesting idea. It also captures devices that get disposed. I don't believe that it's possible to force a notification when an app is uninstalled. This would prevent uninstalling an app offline.

Comment: This is probably the only way to do it. Just google your question, it has already been asked a few times on stackoverflow: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20check%20if%20user%20uninstalled%20app

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, my friend... it would require your app to have an awareness outside the sandbox that it runs in. you have your install/uninstall statistics in the google developer console... but i dont think it reports on a per-user basis.   There's also firebase analytics, maybe that has some way of doing it.